# unable to run docker-compose.yaml on kubernetes?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

The following docker-compose.yaml works perfectly after running with the docker-compose up command. I can also see that my app has successfully started in tomcat manager app.

```
version: '3'
services:
      mysql:
        image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
        ports:
          - "3306:3306"
       tomcat:
        image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
        container_name: tomcat7hope
        ports:
          - "8080:8080"
```

Now since I want to run this on kubernetes, I converted this to kubernetes using kompose convert which gave me 4 kubernetes yaml files :

1.tomcatservice.yaml

2.mysqlservice.yaml

3.tomcatdeployment.yaml

4.mysqldeployment.yaml

I changed the spec type to NodePort in tomcatservice.yaml.

this time the problem is that the app has not started in tomcat's manager app and starting it gives me Application at context path /data-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT could not be started Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component

It's so strange because the same app ran succesfully using docker-compose up.
Do i have to change anything else in the kubernetes yaml files??

I feel like i have missed out on something!! please help

Comment: Did you push the current version of your image to the registry?

Comment: both the images were built using docker files and then  i pushed them to my public repository in docker hub

Comment: do your  tomcat and mysql pods up and running ? `kubectl get pods `

Comment: yes they are running

Comment: maybe i should use shared volume??

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Comment: it'll be hard to troubleshoot without yaml files. Can you share them?  Also the output of `kubectl get pods -o wide`